# What is the easiest way to ignore a JPA field during persistence?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I'm essentially looking for a "@Ignore" type annotation with which I can stop a particular field from being persisted. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 576, accepted):

[`@Transient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) complies with your needs.

Comment: But then jackson will not serialize the field when converting to JSON...how to solve?

Comment: that depends on your app desing. if you annotate your entity class - it applies everywhere; but if you anotate dao that use entity - it's another story. in short: use DAO when you have multiple storages

Comment: Doesn't work on List fields. For Collection type fields, hibernate actually creates a new intermediate table. Any workaround for that ?

Comment: @MobileMon  You can solve it, check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41850392/3871754

Comment: @MobileMon Preferably you shouldn't be using the same entity for both database and API purposes (single responsibility).

Comment: Thanks for the keyword. Static fields soved my problems both when the datatable and  entity is created. https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/fields#Transient_Fields

Comment: I needed to ignore a List type property for persistence, but include it in my JSON response. When I went to add a Transient annotation to my model property using Eclipse IDE, it suggested four 'Transient' options to import.  This SO question/answer helped me choose the correct implementation of Transient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750977/transient-annotation-org-springframework-data-annotation-transient-annotation/42753469

Answer (score 193):

To ignore a field, annotate it with [`@Transient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) so it will not be mapped by hibernate.

but then **jackson will not serialize** the field when converting to JSON.

**If you need mix JPA with JSON**(omit by JPA but still include in Jackson) use [`@JsonInclude`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html) :

```
@JsonInclude()
@Transient
private String token;
```

**TIP:**

You can also use [JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_NULL) and hide fields in JSON during deserialization when `token == null`:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Transient
private String token;
```

Comment: I'm running JAX-RS 2.0.1 / Jersey 2.25.1 / Jackson 2.8.7 and with that stack `@JsonInclude` is not necessary: `@Transient` fields are still included in JSON. (You still got my vote: the technique itself might be very useful in other circumstances).

Comment: I did it on Spring Boot

Comment: hi,I am trying to use this,but it is not getting serialized with @Transient field

Comment: @Mohammad add annotation @JsonInclude()

Comment: Tried this in Spring Boot 2.1.7 but didn't work. But still you get my vote because it may work in other scenarios.

Comment: `@Transient` fields are only excluded when the jackson-datatype-hibernate module is on the classpath and registered with the ObjectMapper, which might be the default for a Spring Boot application with Jackson and Hibernate, and why setting `@JsonInclude` as well is optional for others.

Answer (score 30):

To ignore a field, annotate it with `@Transient` so it will not be mapped by hibernate.
Source: [Hibernate Annotations](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/orm/hibernate/annotations.html).

Answer (score 26):

This answer comes a little late, but it completes the response.

In order to avoid a field from an entity to be persisted in DB one can use one of the two mechanisms:

[@Transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) - the JPA annotation marking a field as not persistable

**[transient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3)** keyword in java. Beware - using this keyword, will prevent the field to be used with any serialization mechanism from java. So, if the field must be serialized you'd better use just the **@Transient** annotation.

Comment: how about i just want to ignore the persistence on get method?. For example : myjparepository.save() wil save the model as usual , and myjparepository.find(id) will ignore the field that I want?

Comment: @xtiger you can create a custom query to archive that functionality. Here's an example [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

Answer (score 20):

There are multiple solutions depending on the entity attribute type.

### Basic attributes

Consider you have the following `account` table:

[image: The account table]

The `account` table is mapped to the `Account` entity like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User owner;

    private String iban;

    private long cents;

    private double interestRate;

    private Timestamp createdOn;

    @Transient
    private double dollars;

    @Transient
    private long interestCents;

    @Transient
    private double interestDollars;

    @PostLoad
    private void postLoad() {
        this.dollars = cents / 100D;

        long months = createdOn.toLocalDateTime()
            .until(LocalDateTime.now(), ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
        double interestUnrounded = ( ( interestRate / 100D ) * cents * months ) / 12;
        this.interestCents = BigDecimal.valueOf(interestUnrounded)
            .setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN).longValue();

        this.interestDollars = interestCents / 100D;
    }

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The basic entity attributes are mapped to table columns, so properties like `id`, `iban`, `cents` are basic attributes.

But the `dollars`, `interestCents`, and `interestDollars` are computed properties, so you annotate them with `@Transient` to exclude them from SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE SQL statements.

> So, for basic attributes, you need to use `@Transient` in order to exclude a given property from being persisted.

### Associations

Assuming you have the following `post` and `post_comment` tables:

[image: The post and post_comment tables]

You want to map the `latestComment` association in the `Post` entity to the latest `PostComment` entity that was added.

To do that, you can use the `@JoinFormula` annotation:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinFormula("(" +
        "SELECT pc.id " +
        "FROM post_comment pc " +
        "WHERE pc.post_id = id " +
        "ORDER BY pc.created_on DESC " +
        "LIMIT 1" +
    ")")
    private PostComment latestComment;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

When fetching the `Post` entity, you can see that the `latestComment` is fetched, but if you want to modify it, the change is going to be ignored.

> So, for associations, you can use `@JoinFormula` to ignore the write operations while still allowing reading the association.

### @MapsId

Another way to ignore associations that are already mapped by the entity identifier is to use `@MapsId`.

For instance, consider the following one-to-one table relationship:

[image: The post and post_details tables]

The `PostDetails` entity is mapped like this:

```
@Entity(name = "PostDetails")
@Table(name = "post_details")
public class PostDetails {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Date createdOn;
 
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;
 
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Post post;
 
    public PostDetails() {}
 
    public PostDetails(String createdBy) {
        createdOn = new Date();
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Notice that both the `id` attribute and the `post` association map the same database column, which is the `post_details` Primary Key column.

To exclude the `id` attribute, the `@MapsId` annotation will tell Hibernate that the `post` association takes care of the table Primary Key column value.

> So, when the entity identifier and an association share the same column, you can use `@MapsId` to ignore the entity identifier attribute and use the association instead.

### Using `insertable = false, updatable = false`

Another option is to use `insertable = false, updatable = false` for the association which you want to be ignored by Hibernate.

For instance, we can map the previous one-to-one association like this:

```
@Entity(name = "PostDetails")
@Table(name = "post_details")
public class PostDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Post post;

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity

    public void setPost(Post post) {
        this.post = post;
        if (post != null) {
            this.id = post.getId();
        }
    }
}
```

The `insertable` and `updatable` attributes of the `@JoinColumn` annotation will instruct Hibernate to ignore the `post` association since the entity identifier takes care of the `post_id` Primary Key column.

Comment: _Notice that both the id attribute and the post association map the same database column, which is the post_comment Primary Key column._

Is this correct in context of `post` and `post_details` tables as example?

Comment: Thanks for spotting it. I fixed it.

Comment: I tried all of these with DB2 and the only one that I could get to work with the DB2 database is @JoinColumn. PrimaryKeyColumn also did not work. Mostly the generated generated SQL was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent and exhaustive answer! In the `@MapsId` example, the screenshot shows a `post_id` column, and the code example the `@Id private Long id` and `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @MapsId private Post post;` attributes. To make the code example consistent with the screenshot, shouldn't the id-attribute be `@Id private Long post_id`? Maybe I'm missing something, because I don't understand how Hibenate would use the DB column `post_id` (see screenshot) without annotating field `post` with `@JoinColumn(name="post_id")`.

Comment: If you test it, you'll see it works just fine because the id name is taken from the relationship.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes you want to:

1. Serialize a column
2. Ignore column from being persisted:

Use `@Column(name = "columnName", insertable = false, updatable = false)`

A good scenario is when a certain column is automatically calculated by using other column values

Comment: Yeah this solution fits the Scenario

Comment: This is the best solution for me: I want to ignore the column during EntityManager operations but still use it to automatically create the schema 

Answer (score 9):

use @Transient to make JPA ignoring the field.

but! Jackson will not serialize that field as well. to solve just add @JsonProperty

an example

```
@Transient
@JsonProperty
private boolean locked;
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

To complete the above answers, I had the case using an XML mapping file where neither the `@Transient` nor `transient` worked...
I had to put the transient information in the xml file:

```
<attributes>
(...)
    <transient name="field" />
</attributes>
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the above answers worked for me using Hibernate 5.2.10, Jersey 2.25.1 and Jackson 2.8.9. I finally found the answer (sort of, they reference hibernate4module but it works for 5 too) [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/573). None of the Json annotations worked at all with `@Transient`. Apparently Jackson2 is 'smart' enough to kindly ignore stuff marked with `@Transient` unless you explicitly tell it not to. The key was to add the hibernate5 module (which I was using to deal with other Hibernate annotations) and disable the `USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION` feature in my Jersey Application:

```
ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Hibernate5Module jacksonHibernateModule = new Hibernate5Module();
jacksonHibernateModule.disable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
jacksonObjectMapper.registerModule(jacksonHibernateModule);
```

Here is the dependency for the Hibernate5Module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: After trying every other method mention above and others 
`@JsonProperty`
`@JsonInclude`
`@JsonSerialize + @JsonDeserialize` `mapper.configure(MapperFeature.PROPAGATE_TRANSIENT_MARKER, false));`
this solution finally worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, using Hibernate5Module, the @Transient will not be serialize if using ObjectMapper. Removing will make it work.

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class TransientFieldTest {

    @Test
    public void Print_Json() throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper objectEntityMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //objectEntityMapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
        objectEntityMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

        log.info("object: {}", objectEntityMapper.writeValueAsString( //
                SampleTransient.builder()
                               .id("id")
                               .transientField("transientField")
                               .build()));

    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder
    private static class SampleTransient {

        private String id;

        @Transient
        private String transientField;

        private String nullField;

    }
}
```