# Make Hibernate ignore instance variables that are not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I thought hibernate takes into consideration only instance variables that are annotated with `@Column`.  But strangely today when I added a variable (that is not mapped to any column, just a variable i need in the class), it is trying to include that variable in the select statement as a column name and throws the error -

> Unknown column 'team1_.agencyName' in 'field list'

My class -

```
@Entity
@Table(name="team")
public class Team extends BaseObject implements Serializable {

@Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(length=50)
private String name;

@Column(length=10)
private String code;

@Column(name = "agency_id")
private Long agencyId;

private String agencyName; //note: not annotated.

}
```

FYI...I use the above class in another class with many to many mapping

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
@JoinTable(
        name="user_team",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name="user_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="team_id")
)    
public Set<Team> getTeams() {
    return teams;
}
```

Why is this happening?!

Comment: very sorry...i am new to this.  will do it for all my posts! thanks for telling.

Comment: @Tunaki no, this is not exactly duplicate of question "JPA fastest way to ignore a field during persistence?" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281952/jpa-fastest-way-to-ignore-a-field-during-persistence) This ticket is about Hibernate, and the other one is talking about JPA instead.

Comment: @hese does your base class have some variables? If yes does hibernate ignore them or take into account?

Answer (score 476, accepted):

JPA will use *all* properties of the class, unless you specifically mark them with `@Transient`:

```
@Transient
private String agencyName;
```

The `@Column` annotation is purely optional, and is there to let you override the auto-generated column name. Furthermore, the `length` attribute of `@Column`  is only used when auto-generating table definitions, it has no effect on the runtime.

Comment: you can also use the java modifier `transient` instead of the annotation

Comment: Is it possible that the variable to be ignored only when persisting, but when fetching the data from the DB, the field can be taken into account ?

Comment: Thanks to @CodeMed's answer below, don't import the wrong package : `import javax.persistence.Transient;`

Answer (score 96):

For folks who find this posting through the search engines, another possible cause of this problem is from importing the wrong package version of `@Transient`.  Make sure that you import `javax.persistence.transient` and not some other package.

Comment: thanks. I was wondering if it should be beans, or persistence.

Comment: thanks, was using org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient and was confused why it does not work.

Comment: thank you!!!  funny, was thinking, do i really need another google search, the accepted answer was so probable.....

Answer (score 32):

Placing `@Transient` on getter with private field worked for me.

```
    private String name;

    @Transient
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Comment: Putting @Transient at getter level worked for me too.

Comment: Is it no different from declaring the variable `@Transient`?

Comment: @ADTC depending on the libraries used, some balk at annotations on getter/setters, others do not (recently noticed this with Moxy and Jackson; Moxy's great because it fails silently without reason), some don't like them to be mixed (between properties and getter/setters). Gotta love it.