# Can't I use @Value annotation with @Transient annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, hibernate-annotations, spring-annotations

I have a class to map a table for using hibernate. There are some variable I want to ignore for mapping to use as constant. And I want to load constant value from properties so I code it like this:

```
@Transient
@Value("${something.value}")
private int MY_VALUE;
```

But, the value of `MY_VALUE` is always set to 0. Can't I use @Transient annotation with @Value annotation? Or I missed something else?

Comment: if you remove the `@Transient` annotation, it continues to be set to `0`?

Comment: @bluefoot If I remove that the project throws error, because of this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662582/how-to-make-hibernate-ignore-class-variables-that-are-not-mapped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `@Value` to specify a property value to load when Spring creates the bean.

However, if you are using Hibernate to load data from a database, Spring is not instantiating these classes for you. So your `@Value` annotation has no effect.

I would suggest injecting the `@Value` into the DAO that loads these entities from Hibernate, something like

```
public class FooDao {
    @Value("...")
    private int yourConfiguredValue;

    public getFoo() {
        Foo foo = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(...);
        foo.setYourValue(yourConfiguredValue);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get `foo` as a list like `List<Foo> foos = ...`. Is it good idea to inject the `@Value` into every objects with loop?

Comment: Well if you need to add the value to each object, what other way is there? However I would consider not having this value attached to the entity object at all if it's constant and/or from a properties file - doesn't sound like it's related to *each* instance of Foo, especially if they all have the same value. I'd attach that @Value to some other class.

Answer (score 6):

Those two annotations belong in different domains.

`@Transient` belongs to an entity, while `@Value` belongs to Spring Beans. Entities are managed by JPA / Hibernate, Spring Beans are managed by Spring. It is not a good idea to mix the two.

You *could* achieve this by [using the `@Configurable` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) and AspectJ compilation or Load Time Weaving, but I would strongly advise against such a hack. Use a Spring Bean to hold a `@Value`, not an entity!

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I have a class Employee which has relation with class Organization.

I don't want to serialize a whole dependent object(Organization), rather serialize a single parameter of organization(e.g. orgID).

I tried following:

```
@Transient
@value("#{target.orgId.id}")
private UUID org_Id;
```

but it didnt work. So i used a simple getter mehtod instead of a field variable as follows:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "orgID")
private Organization orgId;

@JsonProperty("orgId")
public UUID getOrg_ID() {
    return orgId.getId();
}
```

it worked and i got simple orgId field in response serialized by Jackson.
It seems Jackson work with getters without considering a field variable is declared or not corresponding to that getter method.