# Hibernate not giving any error

Tags: java, hibernate

I added the following method to one of my application entity.

```
public boolean isSame(TaskUser taskUser){
        //some work
    }
```

However I came across few threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359346/how-to-make-hibernate-ignore-a-method) regarding hibernate errors for such kind of methods used without **@Transient**. But my application is running fine and also there is no column created in my DB table for the entity, so as a learner I want to ask what actually happens that save my app from hibernate error. Is that argument passed the reason?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359346/how-to-make-hibernate-ignore-a-method ..... from here some questions arises to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method does not define a property, so Hibernate is not interested in mapping a column for it.

The reason is that it is not a "getter". It does have the proper name ("isXXX" for a boolean), but it takes a parameter. Getters must be without parameters.

If it was a "real" getter, and you did not want it to result in a persistent property, you could use `@Transient` to suppress the automatic mapping.