# How to ignore hibernate List<>[] arrays methods from being scanned during startup?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a spring-boot application with JPA, and I have the following mapping class:

```java
@Entity
public class Entry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ENTRY_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ENTRY_SEQ", sequenceName = "ENTRY_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONSTR_TABLE_ID", nullable = false)
    private ConstraintTable constraintTable;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entry", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<EntryValue> entryValues = new ArrayList<>();

   // default getters and setters


   public List<EntryValue>[] createValuesGroupedByColumn() {
       return null;
   }
}
```

Every time I start my application it throws the following exception:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PropertyTypeExtractor available for type void
```

It's caused because `List<EntryValue>[]` it's not a valid type supported in `JavaReflectionManager.toXType`, it only supports arrays, collections and simple types. However I would like to have this method and configure hibernate to ignore it.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359346/how-to-make-hibernate-ignore-a-method) was suggested to use the `@Transient` annotation, but it didn't work. I tried different names that don't start with `[get|set|is]AttrName` (the standard bean convention) and also didn't work. Is there someway I can ignore this method from being scanned by hibernate during initialization?

Comment: This bug ? https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13560

Comment: Yes, I didn't see it. Well I think I will have to wait then. At least, we have a link between SO and Hibernate's Jira for this error.