# Adding extra fields in hibernate beans that are not fields in db table

Tags: hibernate

Is it possible to add extra member variables in hibernate beans that are not fields in the actual database?

eg. I need to add hasComments a member variable in MyEntity, and has comments is not an actual field in the db.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make hibernate ignore class variables that are not mapped!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662582/how-to-make-hibernate-ignore-class-variables-that-are-not-mapped)

Answer (score 4):

Let either the field be transient, or annotate it with the [@Transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) annotation.

Comment: I tried adding Transient annotation 

but while I try to read a record from db it gives the following exception 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [com.en.server.domain.Myentity#1]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'myentity0_.hasComments' in 'field list'..
What could be the issue?

Comment: Could you paste your class in your question?

Answer (score 1):

See this

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "comment")
private String comment;

@Column(name = "time")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
private Date time;
```

@Transient
private String information;

Answer (score 0):

For a quick hack to move past this error during development, you can use `hbm2ddl` to create the database automatically from the hibernate mappings, and it will create fields in the table for the `transient` properties.  This does not solve the long term problem, but it lets you continue to work on other things until you have time to resolve the underlying issue.