# Creating other public methods in entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have an Entity class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "rule")
    public class Rule implements Cloneable, Serializable, IPojoGenEntity, IRule, SequencedEntity {

    private String name;

    private Service service;

    //getter .. setter for service and name

      public String getServiceName() {
        return (this.service.getName());
      }

     public void setServiceName(String servicename) {
       this.service.setName(servicename);
     }

    }
```

I am getting exception for getting service name through RulClass object

```
public String getServiceName() {
        return (this.service.getName());
      }
```

Stack Trace

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: "RULE0_.SERVICENAME" is not valid in the context where it is used.
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.fg.e(fg.java:1596)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.fg.a(fg.java:1206)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.gb.g(gb.java:140)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.gb.a(gb.java:39)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.w.a(w.java:34)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.vb.g(vb.java:139)
```

Can we use such getter and setter in an entity class?

I am using **hibernate, spring, DB2, IBM WebSphere**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **serviceName** was not a member of Rule class so there is a problem with method name. Name cannot be like

```
getServiceName
setServiceName
```

rather it should be something **other than** `get` or `set` `prefix`

```
fetchServiceName
addServiceName
```

Answer (score 1):

You should either make it `@Transient` as it was mentioned if you don't want to store it

OR

Define 
@javax.persistence.Column(name = "service_id") field annotation for the getter to let hibernate know which column to use.

OR

Rename DB to have the service field "SERVICENAME" to use default column name

Answer (score 0):

There is the `Transient` annotation to tell Hibernate to ignore a field.  So:

```
@Transient
private Service service;
```

From very similar SO question: [Make hibernate ignore class variables that are not mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662582/how-to-make-hibernate-ignore-class-variables-that-are-not-mapped).

Comment: No No. I want to save this service field. I am just getting its (service) members in Rule class also.

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Comment: Rule class will have two members. name and Service. Service will have only name