# fetch attributes in hibernate with specific order

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the below scenario :

```
class GraphUser {

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName = "";

    @Column(name="middle_name")
    private String middleName = "";

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName = "";

    @Column(name="start_point")
    private String startPointId = "";

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "points")

    private HashMap<Point> points= new HashMap<Point>();

    private Point startPoint = points.get(startPointId);

}
```

there are any way to force hibernate to fetch the startPointId  , points before creation of startPoint attribute to get the right value?

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need a property**, just use a transient getter. You call it each time you need to get the start point.

```
@Transient
public Point getStartPoint() {
   return points.get(startPointId);
}
```

This will work with no hassle (provided the `FetchType` of `points` is `EAGER`), and Hibernate will safely ignore it.
Actually, there might be a slight performance loss in querying the `HashMap` each time, but I wouldn't bother with that.

Furthermore, I suggest you to replace `HashMap` in the declaration of `points` with `Map`, i.e.:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "points")
private Map<Point> points = new HashMap<Point>();
```

(update getters and setters accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

Do the `startPoint` assignment in the setter for `startPointId`, or just in the getter for `startPoint`. And `startPoint` should probably be [`transient` or `@Transient` so Hibernate doesn't muck with it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4662599/139010).

```
public void setStartPointId(String startPointId) {
    this.startPointId = startPointId;
    this.startPoint = points.get(startPointId);
}

// or

public Point getStartPoint() {
    if (this.startPoint == null) {
        this.startPoint = points.get(startPointId);
    }
    return this.startPoint;
}

public void setStartPointId(String startPointId) {
    this.startPointId = startPointId;
    this.startPoint = null;
}
```

Comment: the problem is in some times the points map is still empty and not fetched from the data base so i am need any way to force it to be filled before calling getStartPoint().