# Hibernate Lazy Load and @Transient

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, lazy-loading, transient

I have a Java Spring MVC controller application. It uses **hibernate 4 and spring 3**. Using *Bitronix transaction manager*

Here are some of my model classes

**User.java**

```
    public class User  implements java.io.Serializable {

        private Integer userId;
        private String userName;
        private String emailId;
        private Set<Jobs> jobses = new HashSet<Jobs>(0);

        //getters and setters   

        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="user")
        public Set<Jobs> getJobses() {
            return this.jobses;
        }

        public void setJobses(Set<Jobs> jobses) {
            this.jobses = jobses;
        }
    }
```

**Jobs.java**

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name = "findJobsByUser",
        query = "from Jobs jobs where jobs.user = :user"
    )
})
@JsonIgnoreProperties("user")
@Entity
@Table(name="jobs"
    ,catalog="mydb"
)
public class Jobs  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer jobId;
    private User user;
    private String jobName;
    private Set<Tasks> taskses = new HashSet<Tasks>(0);
    //getters & setters

    @Transient
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="UserId")
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="jobs")
    public Set<Tasks> getTaskses() {
        return this.taskses;
    }

    public void setTaskses(Set<Tasks> taskses) {
        this.taskses = taskses;
    }
}
```

**Tasks.java**

```
public class Tasks  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer taskId;
    private Jobs jobs;
    private String taskName;
    private Set<Process> processes = new HashSet<Process>(0);

    //getters & setters

    @Transient
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="JobId")
    public Jobs getJobs() {
        return this.jobs;
    }

    public void setJobs(Jobs jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="tasks")
    public Set<Process> getProcesses() {
        return this.processes;
    }

    public void setProcesses(Set<Process> processes) {
        this.processes = processes;
    }
}
```

**Process.java**

```
public class Process  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer processId;
    private Tasks tasks;
    private String processName;

    //getters and setters

    @Transient
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="TaskId")
    public Tasks getTasks() {
        return this.tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(Tasks tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

}
```

In my controller using *Named Query* I am trying to get all Jobs.

**JobsDetailsController.java controller method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/jobsdeatils/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Jobs> jobsDetails(@PathVariable Integer userId) throws IOException {
    try {
        User user=userService.findById(userId);

        Map<String, Object> queryParams=new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(); 

        queryParams.put("user", user);

        jobs=jobsService.findByNamedQuery("findJobsByUser", queryParams);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
    return jobs;
}
```

What I want is, when I retrieve `List<Jobs>`, I want tasks, then inside tasks, I don't want the hibernate to set value for `jobs` object. And also in `Process` I don't want to set for `tasks` object.

To ignore a property I heard to use `@Transient` from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662582/how-to-make-hibernate-ignore-class-variables-that-are-not-mapped).

This is my test case

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("classpath:webapptest")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-applicationcontext.xml"})
public class FindJobsControllerTest {

private MockMvc springMvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wContext;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void documentsPollingTest() throws Exception {
        ResultActions resultActions=springMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/jobsdeatils/2").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        resultActions.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
        resultActions.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
}
```

But when I start the test, I am getting exception as `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`

Folowing is the trace

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.org.myapp.model.Jobs.user in com.org.myapp.model.User.jobses
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:668)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1593)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1350)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:242)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 65 more
```

Why is that? And how can I solve?

I could try without `@Transient`, But for large data I need to wait for long time and also JSON string I am not able to get in my client side application. I am using JSON ignore properties, But still it takes time to retrieve from hibernate.