# what happens in hibernate if i give a column tag for a transient variable?

Tags: java, hibernate, transient

What happens in hibernate if i give a column tag for a transient variable?

```
@Table(name="team")
public class Team extends BaseObject implements Serializable {

@Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(length=50)
private String name;

@Column(length=10)
private String code;

@Column(name = "agency_id")
private Long agencyId;

@Column(name = "agency_name")
private transient String agencyName; 



}
```

Comment: Here is the discussion, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662582/how-to-make-hibernate-ignore-class-variables-that-are-not-mapped.

Comment: Are you talking about `transient` (a keyword) as implied by `private transient String agencyName;`. If it is so, the field will not be serialized. If you are however, talking about the annotation `@Transient` (`javax.persistence.Transient`), the field will not be persisted to the database (nor its value will be retrieved - needless to mention).

Answer (score 1):

Field is not persistent. You will not get field value from database, changes will not be commited.

[JSR 220 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)

> If the entity has field-based access, the persistence provider runtime accesses instance variables directly. All non-transient instance variables that are not annotated with the Transient annotation are persistent.