# could not extract ResultSet org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException

Tags: javascript, java, hibernate

i'm not able to fetch the result,  create query is getting executed but the after that converting that into list is not working. please help me to resolve this problem.
why it is not getting converted into list
i'm not able to fetch the result,  create query is getting executed but the after that converting that into list is not working. please help me to resolve this problem.
why it is not getting converted into list

Tablescript

```
CREATE TABLE Answer(
answerId   INTEGER,
questionId   INTEGER NOT NULL,
userId varchar2(40) NOT NULL,
answerString VARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_Answer_answerId PRIMARY KEY(answerId)
);
```

bean class

```
public class Answer {
private Integer answerId;
private Integer questionId;
private String userId;
private String answerString;
private String message;

public Integer getAnswerId() {
    return answerId;
}

public void setAnswerId(Integer answerId) {
    this.answerId = answerId;
}

public String getAnswerString() {
    return answerString;
}

public void setAnswerString(String answerString) {
    this.answerString = answerString;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public Integer getQuestionId() {
    return questionId;
}

public void setQuestionId(Integer questionId) {
    this.questionId = questionId;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}}
```

controller method is:

```
$scope.tagForm.getAnswer = function(val) {
    alert("hi");
    window.location = "#/answer";
    $scope.tagForm.ans = null;
    var data = JSON.stringify($scope.tagForm);
    $http.post(URI + "tag/ans/"+val,data).then(function(response) {
        alert("hey");
        //var string=response.data;
        //var formattedString = string.join("\n");
        //$scope.askForm.message =formattedString;
        $scope.tagForm.ans =response.data;
        //alert($scope.tagForm.message);
    }, function(response) {
        $scope.tagForm.message = null;
    });
    };



@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
public Map<Integer, String> getAnswer(Integer question) throws Exception {
    Map<Integer, String> quesString = null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session = null;
    List<AnswerEntity> custList1 = new ArrayList<AnswerEntity>();
    try {
        quesString = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        AnswerEntity tag = new AnswerEntity();
        // Question q=new Question();
        // q.setTagId(question);
        // ques.setQuestionString(question.getQuestionString());
        System.out.println("dao" + question);

        // session.persist(ques);

        // session.getTransaction().begin();
        System.out.println("before query exec");
        Query query = session
                .createQuery("from AnswerEntity where questionId=?");
        query.setInteger(0, question);
        System.out.println(query);
        System.out.println("after query exec");
        custList1 = query.list();
        System.out.println(custList1.size());
        // List list = query.list();
        for (AnswerEntity tagEntity : custList1) {
            // System.out.println("Question ID=>"+tagEntity.getQuestionId()+"\nQuestion String=>"+tagEntity.getQuestionString());
            // List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
            Answer a = new Answer();
            a.setQuestionId(tagEntity.getQuestionId());
            a.setAnswerString(tagEntity.getAnswerString());
            // newList.addAll(getTag(tagEntity.getQuestionId()));
            // String a=String.valueOf(tagEntity.getQuestionId());
            quesString.put(a.getQuestionId(), a.getAnswerString());

            // quesString.add(a);
            // quesString.addAll(newList);

        }
        // session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (HibernateException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw exception;
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen() || session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return quesString;
}
```

errorlog

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
>       at com.infy.dao.TagDAOImpl.getAnswer(TagDAOImpl.java:122)
>       at com.infy.service.TagServiceImpl.getAnswer(TagServiceImpl.java:55)
>       at com.infy.api.TagAPI.fetchTagList2(TagAPI.java:65)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:317)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:298)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "ANSWERENTI0_"."MESSAGE": invalid identifier

**AnswerEntity Class**

```
public class AnswerEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generatorName")
private Integer answerId;
private Integer questionId;
private String userId;
private String answerString;
private String message;

public Integer getAnswerId() {
    return answerId;
}

public void setAnswerId(Integer answerId) {
    this.answerId = answerId;
}

public String getAnswerString() {
    return answerString;
}

public void setAnswerString(String answerString) {
    this.answerString = answerString;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public Integer getQuestionId() {
    return questionId;
}

public void setQuestionId(Integer questionId) {
    this.questionId = questionId;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}}
```

Comment: What is `AnswerEntity`? Please provide code for it also.

Comment: You should provide an error log of exception and versions of hibernate you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have property `message` in your entity class but you do not have corresponding column in database. This is clearly identified in stack trace:

```
ORA-00904: "ANSWERENTI0_"."MESSAGE": invalid identifier
```

You need either to create column if you want to store that information in the database or remove it from your entity class or mark it with `@Transient` to ask hibernate to ignore it in SQL queries like in this question: [Make hibernate ignore class variables that are not mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662582/make-hibernate-ignore-class-variables-that-are-not-mapped)

Comment: oh yea that's what the problem was, thank you so much

Comment: This is it! I had inconsistent column names in Entity class and actual table. In fact one additional unused column in entity class.