# JPA Entity static logger

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, logging, static, log4j

My question is, can i use a static logger in a JPA Entity, or will it cause some problem?
I would like to do something like this (the logger is log4j):

```
    @Entity
public class AlertRule implements Serializable {
/**
 * Serial version ID.
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 9000392523924653431L;

/**Logger. */
transient private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AlertRule.class);

/**
 * ID.
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;

/**
 * Rule name.
 */
@NotNull
private String name;

...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With standard JPA, static fields are not persisted, and final fields are not persisted, so its not a problem

Comment: And what if i use cache: @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)? In fact we have some memory leaks, and the heap dump showed this entity...

Comment: the class is initialised and it creates a Logger, that's all there is. The persistence process (whichever JPA impl you use) should do nothing with it (DataNucleus JPA certainly doesn't).

Comment: If your logger is not static, use @Transient. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281952/jpa-fastest-way-to-ignore-a-field-during-persistence