# @Transient in spring data doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have `Settlement` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "settlement")
public class Settlement {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subscription_x_product_id")
    private ProductSubscription productSubscription;
```

which related to `ProductSubscription` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subscriptionproduct")
public class ProductSubscription {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
```

which related to `Product` entity

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Transient
    private String enabled;
```

in `Product` entity i have field `enabled` which annotated with `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient`. 
also I have Repository

```
public interface SettlementRepository extends JpaRepository<Settlement, Integer>
```

when I call `SettlementRepository.findAll();`  it give exception `Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'enabled'.`

How can I ignore the `enabled` field from being loaded from the DB ?

Comment: Do you have some Annotation on the setter of `enabled`?

Comment: @Jens no i don,t have any Annotations on the setter or the getter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was in Annotation `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` once I changed to [`@javax.persistence.Transient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) it worked fine.

Comment: I've the same problem but I was using `@Transient` from `@javax.persistence.Transient` from the beginning but still no success. I save the entity and call the get method on the returned object and the value was persisted. Have you found something else? Thanks.

Comment: For further readers, the annotation is actually working, but as I'm using it in a `@Transactional` Test, spring repository seems to be not updating the Object (the object saved and the returned from the repository have the same Object Id). So the field was not being written in the database but the Repository is still returning it, even if I call the findOne and assigns it to a new variable. Still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @fabioresner something error in your enitty (for me, I had wrong \@UniqueConstraint name) and you must defined query in xml file like this:
<named-native-query name="abc"
        result-class="com.xyz.entity.MyEnttity">
        <query><![CDATA[SELECT * from tableName where id = :myId]]></query>
    </named-native-query>

Comment: @fabioresner check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753469/5695421