# Can Spring JPA Entity Class Contain Non-DB Fields that Are not In a DB Table

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring JPA and Spring Data Rest with SpringBoot.  I have a DB table called user and an entity for this table.  I have no controller for this application.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Integer userid;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String username;
}
```

And now, I need to add one more field which isn't a column in the USER table.  It will be used by some monitoring tool for tracing purpose.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Integer userid;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String username;

    private String tracer;  // this field is not in DB
}
```

I am getting a jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid column name "tracer" after adding this field, which makes sense because this class is annotated as an entity.  My question is that: is there a way to add a non-db field into an entity class?  I guess not, but would like to know in case someone has a solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, just add the annotation `@Transient` to your field.

You can read more from the API docs:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html

And here (section 37.1.2.1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro001.htm#BNBQA

Hope it helps.

Comment: Be sure to use the correct @Transient, namely javax.persistence.Transient (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753469/3368818).

Comment: Yes, and it's in the docs linked in the answer!