# How to prevent Spring boot from creating column for some particular field in modal

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a modal in the spring boot application where that modal is an entity. But I want to exclude one field from creating a column from that modal.

For instance, below given is my fields in the modal 'Demo'

-field1

-field2

-field3 \\ I don't want field3 to be added as a column inside the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u check `@Transient` ?

Comment: @pvpkiran Thanks buddy. It's working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1281952/4506703